# Why does Nautilus behave differently for ssh:// vs ftp://?

Tags: ssh, nautilus, ftp, 22.04

Why is there a difference in performance and behavior in Nautilus if I access my NAS using `ssh` vs. `ftp`?

(I already know that `ssh` gets replaced by `sftp` in the Nautilus pathbar).

I expected Nautilus to behave the same for `ssh`(i.e. `sftp`) and `ftp`, once the correct credentials are entered. Furthermore, I expected `ftp` performance to be better, because we don't have to deal with encryption/decryption overhead.

However...

**If I use `ssh://server.local` in the nautilus path bar, Nautilus...**

- will list all files on the NAS server that are owned by me
- open all files  on the NAS server that are owned by me
- can open `*.pdf` files
- performance is very good
- even displays a thumbnail containing an image of the PDF document...
  [image]

**If I use `ftp://server.local` in the nautilus path bar, Nautilus...**

- will list all files on the NAS server that are owned by me
- can *not* open all files on the NAS server that are owned by me
- can *only* open `*.txt` or image (`*.png`, `*.jpg`, etc.) files
- can *not* open `*.pdf` files
- performance is *slow*, compared to `ssh`
- only shows a *generic* thumbnail for the PDF document...

  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP & FTP have nothing to do with each other despite their names.
From Wikipedia:

> SFTP is not FTP run over SSH, but rather a new protocol designed from the ground up by the IETF SECSH working group. It is sometimes confused with Simple File Transfer Protocol.

The server code that handles it is different, and the client code is also different.

Hence you'll see different behavior and different qualities. It's like comparing FTP vs SMB. They're different.

FTP is very old and was designed for simple listing, uploading and downloading of single files. It was also designed back when download speeds were measured in bytes. It's very limited in its capabilities.

SFTP is much more complete in the functionality it provides as it came much later, and it works very well when both server & clients are Linux because stuff like file permissions and user ownership are handled well.

Comment: That explains it. Based on this information, I think SFTP (SSH) is probably the only viable option for exchanging files using a file browser in Ubuntu, then. SMB does not honor Linux file names, and FTP doesn't seem to work (based on my experience in the question).